# get counts of combinations when countries occur together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
Location 1 | Location 2 | ID (autoIncremented)
```

The location rows are in this sytax:

```
Country*State*City
```

So I can have rows such as this:

```
USA*NY*BROOKLYN
USA*WASHINGTON*SEATTLE
USA*WASHINGTOM*BELLINGHAM
CANADA*BC*VANCOUVER
CANADA*MANITOBA*WINNIPEG
MEXICO*MEHICO*MEXICOCITY
```

I would like to get a result such as this:

```
Country 1 | Country 2 | count([count of all the occurrences together])
```

But I am stuck on achieving this . I would like to count the combinations of countries which occur together. I need to extract the country part of the, so I use:

```
substring_index(location1, '*', 1) as country
```

The closest complete query I have, but is not working proeperly is:

```
select 
substring_index(location1, '*', 1) as country1,
substring_index(location2, '*', 1) as country2
count(*)
FROM location_table
GROUP BY [not sure which to group by]
```

Comment: have you heard of normalisation? Less pain. Trust me!

Comment: I don't have access to modify the schema (DDL), I can only DML

Comment: In your example the 3rd row has a space (and not asterisk) as the first delimiter.  Was it intentional?

Comment: OK: go find the person you designed it this way, and give them a good hard kick up the arse!

Comment: @PM77-1 I have fixed it, there was supposed to be an asterix

Comment: @user2924127, add substring_index statements to the group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can use aliases in the `group by`, so if you want to preserve the ordering:

```
SELECT substring_index(location1, '*', 1) as country1,
       substring_index(location2, '*', 1) as country2,
       count(*)
FROM location_table
GROUP BY country1, country2;
```

If you want all pairs regardless of ordering:

```
SELECT LEAST(substring_index(location1, '*', 1), substring_index(location2, '*', 1)) as country1,
       GREATEST(substring_index(location1, '*', 1), substring_index(location2, '*', 1)) as country2,
       count(*)
FROM location_table
GROUP BY country1, country2;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add country 1 and country 2 need to be counted as separate. For example USA | CANADA and CANADA | USA are distinct and unique.

Comment: @user2924127 . . . That would be the first query.

Answer (score 2):

Below is one of the options.  This is not a valid SQL (since I'm using **aliases** in `GROUP BY`) - just an illustration of my idea. You will need to use your `substring` expressions as the penalty for using not normalized data.

```
GROUP BY ( LEAST(country1, country2) + GREATEST(country1, country2) )
```

The above assumes that `USA | CANADA` and `CANADA | USA` should be counted together.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add country 1 and country 2 need to be counted as separate. For example USA | CANADA and CANADA | USA are distinct and unique.

Comment: In such case you need a trivial `GROUP BY country1, country2` as others suggested.